# Flash content not loding fully in C# form with web browser object with IE 8 and flash version > 10.0

Tags: c#, flash, internet-explorer-8

I am developing a C# apllication for Windows 7 in which I want to load some flash content from a URL in a web browser object inside a form. I want to make the form invisible and dump the bmp images captured from the form to the harddisk.I want to make the application invisible in the task bar and the alt + tab menu also. I tested the app and found out the following scenarios...

Scenario 1:

a. IE 9 installed in the system

b. Flash version 10.0 or 10.1 or 10.2 or 10.3

c. Form set to visible or invisible

d. App set to invisible or visible in task bar and alt +tab menu

Result: Flash content is loaded fully.

Scenario 2:

a. IE 8 installed in the system

b. Flash version 10.0

c. Form set to visible or invisible

d. App set to invisible or visible in task bar and alt +tab menu

Result: Flash content is loaded fully.

Scenario 3:

a. IE 8 installed in the system

b. Flash version 10.1 or 10.2 or 10.3

c. Form set to invisible

d. App set to invisible in task bar and alt + tab menu

Result: Flash content is NOT loaded fully. The content rendering stops at a        certain point. :(

Scenario 4:

a. IE 8 installed in the system

b. Flash version 10.1 or 10.2 or 10.3

c. Form set to visible

d. App set to invisible in task bar and alt + tab menu

Result: Flash content is loaded fully.

Scenario 5:

a. IE 8 installed in the system

b. Flash version 10.1 or 10.2 or 10.3

c. Form set to invisible

d. App set to VISIBLE in task bar and alt + tab menu

Result: Flash content is loaded fully.

Content is loaded fully when I open the link manually in any web browser.

So the the content is not loaded properly in Scenario 3 only (which is my required scenario :( )

Can you please give any insight about this behaviour?
What is the relation between the visible property and flash content loading?

As seen from the above scenarios, I have the problem with IE 8 only.

The same results are observed if I use AxWebbrowser instead of the default web browser object available in dot Net 3.5.